# Validating xml files from Fileuploads

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, file-upload

I've written a c# code for uploading xml files asp.net to dB, I need to allow only xml files and get a validation message. I did use "accept=.xml" but whenever i choose other files, i get error, I want a validation message instead.
Here's my code .

```
{

    FileUploadXml.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/") + FileUploadXml.FileName);

    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=xxx;User Id=xxx;Password='xxx';Initial Catalog=x;Intxxegrated Security=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"))

    {
        sqlCon.Open();

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + FileUploadXml.FileName));
        XmlNode parent = doc.FirstChild.NextSibling;
        XmlNodeList elemList = parent.SelectNodes("Configuration");

        foreach (XmlNode item in elemList)
        {
            string group = item.SelectSingleNode("Group").InnerText;
            string key = item.SelectSingleNode("Key").InnerText;
            string label = item.SelectSingleNode("Label").InnerText;


            string query = "INSERT INTO process_xml_data VALUES (@configtype,@group,@key,@label)";
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@configtype", ddConfigXml.SelectedIndex + 1);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@group", group.Trim());
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", key.Trim());
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@label", label.Trim());
            lblStatusXml.Text = "File Uploaded";
            lblStatusXml.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;


            try
            {
                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {


            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: before you run all that xml code, just check the file extension from the up-load, and then give a message to that effect. In other words, check the file extension in your above posted code first, and don't run the xml code.

Comment: yeah but how? i know the logic but i dont know to implement

Comment: Ok, see my answer + code below.

Answer (score 0):

So, it not clear why the client side filter can't be used, but then again, we don't really have to care, do we?

Thus this:

```
        if (Path.GetExtension(FileUploadXml.FileName) != "xml")
        {
            Response.Write(@"<script>alert('only xml files allowed')</script>");
            return;
        }
        // your code goes here
```